# Can i do a directory listing with git, displaying latest commit dates

Tags: git

I am looking for something like `ls -l` with an extra column that shows the latest commit date of each file (possibly also shortened hash and first line of log message).

Comment: Commits don't store file time stamps, just commit time stamps; and commits don't store file changes either, just files.  So the closest you can get is the commit timestamp, which will be the same for all such files.  Perhaps you want, for each file, the *oldest* commit in which that file is exactly the same as in the `HEAD` commit?

Comment: Commit time stamp is good enough for this purpose. I would like to be able to see, at a quick glance, which files have been modified in the same commit.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD | xargs -I %% sh -c 'echo %% `git log -n 1 "--pretty=format:%C(green)%h (%cr) %C(cyan)%s%Creset" -- %%`'
```

This will print out the file name followed by its last commit hash and date and the subject of the commit.

I’m sure you can make this even nicer but my bash knowledge is a bit limited. My pretty PowerShell solution looks like this:

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD | % { Write-Host ("{0,-30} {1}" -f $_, (git log -n 1 "--pretty=format:%C(green)%h (%cr) %C(blue)%s%Creset" -- $_)) }
```

Comment: The top one gives me: `sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution`

Comment: The below one gives me: `bash: syntax error near unexpected expression "("`

Comment: @ThomasArildsen Sorry, it was missing the second backtick. As for the second, that is for PowerShell on Windows; not bash.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with PowerShell - haven't used Windows for years.
Any chance it can be modified to align the columns?

Comment: @ThomasArildsen You can probably use `columns` or `printf` to align the output in some way but as I said, my bash knowledge is rather limited, so I don’t really know a nicer way atm.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that could work (to be improved for non-tracked files)

```
for i in *; do echo -n "$i - "; git --no-pager log -1 --format='%ad' $i; done
```

You should run that in bash.

Comment: Note that the timestamp you get for a directory is the time of the most recent file commit within that directory or any subdirectory.

Comment: I assume the `| cat` is just to suppress the pager: you can do that without a pipe with `git --no-pager log ...`.

Comment: I'm using this to sort by date: `for i in *; do    if [ -e "$i" ];   then     echo -n "$i - "; git --no-pager log -1 --format='%ad' --date="format:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" $i 2> /dev/null;    fi; done | sort -k 3`